# Type UserControl not defined

Tags: user-controls

I added a user control to the project and checked in to TFS. Now another user get the latest version she cannot see the new user control (uc1) that I added and she is getting type UC1 is not defined. But i do not get the type UC1 is not defined error and I can see the new user control that i added to the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is to check in the project which contains the user control instead of just the user control. So when another user gets the latest from the project they can see the new user control added.